# Accessing private data on a blockchain address using Brownie

Tags: solidity, python, brownie, private

I'm trying to practice on the private data exploit on ethereum and was wondering if there is a function like web3.eth.getStorageAt() implemented in brownie which would allow me to access the storage and private data on blockchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_storage_at is what you're looking for

Comment: Yes that is it, thanks a lot.